# Python regex - only works on online editors, not in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
\([0-9]*,0,(\\[\'\"])(?:\\\\\1|.)*?\1,[0-9]*\)
```

that detects this line and similar lines:

```
(27695426,0,\'\\"General\\"_Julian_Carr\',2)
```

It works on every online regex editor even python written ones, even [this one](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6IlxcKFswLTldKiwwLChcXFxcW1xcJ1xcXCJdKSg%2FOlxcXFxcXFxcXFwxfC4pKj9cXDEsWzAtOV0qXFwpIiwiZmxhZ3MiOjAsIm1hdGNoX3R5cGUiOiJzZWFyY2giLCJ0ZXN0X3N0cmluZyI6IigyNzY5NTQyNiwwLFxcJ1xcXFxcIkdlbmVyYWxcXFxcXCJfSnVsaWFuX0NhcnJcXCcsMikifQ%3D%3D) that gives the code, but it doesn't work in python. This is my code consider

```
import re

regex=r"""\([0-9]*,0,(\\[\'\"])(?:\\\\\1|.)*?\1,[0-9]*\)"""
b= """(27695426,0,\'\\"General\\"_Julian_Carr\',2)"""
print type(re.compile(regex).search(b))
```

which returns NoneType

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Try to use a raw string for b.

Comment: Oh god, this was basically the only thing I didn't try. It works. But to make things more complicated, this line actually comes from a file, how can I make that raw. Also please add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Escape sequences won't be interpreted when reading from a file, so no need to make that "raw".

Comment: As extra info, this `\\\\\1` would match only `Escape + Escapee  + (Escape ' or ")`, roughly `\\\'` or `\\\"`.

Comment: @sln: are you sure it isn't `Bckslsh + Bckslsh + backref`?